# Querying Oracle with a pick list

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, odbc

I have an oracle database that I have read-only access (with no permission to create temporary tables). I have a pick list (in Excel) of 28000 IDs corresponding to 28000 rows in a table which has millions of records. How do I write a query to return the 28000 rows?

I tried creating a table in access and performing a join through ODBC but Access freezes/takes an incredible long time. Would I have to create a query with 28,000 items in an IN statement?

Is there anything in PL/SQL that would make it easier?

Thank you for your time and help.

-JC

Answer (score 3):

What makes your 28,000 rows special?

Is there another field in the records you can use to restrict you query in a WHERE clause (or at least narrow down the millions of rows a bit)? Perhaps the ID's you're interested in fall within a certain range?

Comment: The IDs are actually a combination of a phone number and a time. That's pretty much what makes the row unique.

Comment: I believe Graham is asking what differentiates your 28,000 rows from the millions of rows in the table that you're not interested in.  Can you devise a query that finds those 28,000 rows that doesn't involve 28 separate IN lists of 1000 literals a piece?

Comment: +1, hits the nail on the head. If you can't come up with an answer to this, you're in for one of the painful solutions that others have given.

Comment: They do fall within a certain date range but so do hundreds of thousands of other records. I'm still a bit confused at how this will help me other than perhaps making the query a bit faster. Wouldn't I still have to write multiple IN lists?

Answer (score 0):

The max number of variables for an IN (.., .. ,,) type query is 1000 in Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an index on the table you created in Access.

Answer (score 0):

That's a painful condition to be in.  One workaround is to create a view that contains all of the ids, then join to it.

The example below is Oracle.

```
WITH
ids AS
(
    SELECT 314 ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 159 ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 265 ID FROM DUAL
)
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2
FROM SOME_TABLE, ids
WHERE SOME_TABLE.ID = ids.ID
```

This basically embeds all 28000 ids, in the with clause, allowing you to do the join, without actually creating a table.

Ugly, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is described here: [How to put more than 1000 values into an Oracle IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause/400295#400295)

Comment: Hard to do when you don't have write access to the database.

Comment: Why? Nothing is written in the db!

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to create temporary tables :(

Comment: @JC, The example of the link above doesn't require any temporary tables. Use the '...from table(...' construction!! It is very speedy!