# Is it safe to Insert data in MySQL database using Java.Thread?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

in according to my question above, I need to insert over 20000 thousands rows in one table of my database. In according to the performance I'm searching for a way to increase the efficiency of this process. My first Idea was to realize this with Java.Thread but i not quite sure if this is save enough. Has someone any good advices for me?

Edit: I already use `preparedStatement.addBatch()`

Comment: I don't about multithreading, but u can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195665/java-jdbc-multiple-prepared-statement-bulk-insert

Comment: You can Use stored procedure and call it from your java code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks safe to me, provided that every thread uses a different Connection object, and then disposes of the resources properly.

Anyway, note that the DB itself has a limit on concurrently running requests ([max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) in MySQL), so it doesn't help creating more threads than this number. Also, consider other optimizations such as [batch inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with accessing a database from different threads. As Eyal wrote, just make sure things like Connections only get used with a single thread and properly disposed.

The other question is, if this will actually help your performance. I'd make sure that you did everything else before resorting to multiple threads. Especially using batch statements seems to be the first option to look into if you haven't already.

Comment: I'm benchmarking the combination of Batch and Thread. Is there a possibility to push the whole batch (e.g of 2000 rows) into the DB or is this already done with calling `preparedStatement.executeBatch()`?

Comment: ~10mins for one big batch with ~8000 rows. ~7,5min with 10 Threads and 10 smaller batches. I think this should work to increase the performance.

Comment: The Problem i see is to Synchronize the threads. So i got inconsistence of data insertion if i use more than one thread...

Comment: Well .. "Concurrency is hard" that's why I recommend to check everything else first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need a way to write thousands of query's to your Database. 
Do you know that you can execute a batch of MySQL queries?
There is a question about this already on Stackoverflow,
[Java: Insert multiple rows into MySQL with PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement)

you can use: PreparedStatement#addBatch() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29

and
PreparedStatement#executeBatch()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29

Check out @BalusC 's answer in the link above for more detail.

Comment: see my comment below. And yes i already use batch. Sorry i forgot it to write it down in my question.