# Spring JDBC - Bulk insert targeting multiple tables

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-batch

Using JDBC (Oracle), I need to insert thousands of rows to three different tables. Basically, I want to execute 3 insert SQL statement, one after the other, in a loop.

I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195665/java-jdbc-multiple-prepared-statement-bulk-insert) and I would like to know which implementation is better (in terms of execution time) :

1. Execute the first SQL statement in a batch and retrieve the generated keys
2. Execute the second SQL statement using the generated keys from step 1 in a batch and retrieve new generated keys
3. Exercute the third SQL statement using both generated keys from step 1 and 2

Or looping through each record to insert and for each record executing the 3 SQL statements one after the other.

I know the first implementation is database-dependent (since `ResultSet.getGeneratedKeys()` is not supported by every database). Maybe there is a third implementation I have not thought of?

I want to use a single connection so, for both implementation, I would first get a connection, do every insert and finally commit and close the connection.

Also, I wonder if I can use any of Spring JDBC abstraction. The second implementation seems possible with Spring JdbcTemplace (wrapping the method with `@Transactional` in order to use the same connection) but the first one looks difficult since the method batchUpdate of JdbcTemplate does not return the generated keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the execution time is not an issue, I would go with the second way. It's less error prone and easier to read by another colleague. Plus you have more control over transactions. For example you can commit after the 3 inserts are done.

For the first way: to bypass the `GeneratedKeys` problem you can make `SELECT` after the first set of `INSERTs` and get get the IDs(`GeneratedKeys`) , the make the second set of inserts with the retrieved IDs and so on... But this is messy, I think.

also consider using stored procedure