# Max number of collection elements for IN-clause with jpql

Tags: sql, jpql

I would like to know if there is a limit on the size of a collection when using the IN clause.

select a from A where a.b IN (:c)

and c is a list(for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the specific DBMS, ie. sqlite and postgres have widely different limits (not surprisingly).

**EDIT:**

For Oracle: [How to put more than 1000 values into an Oracle IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause)

For mysql: http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/

Comment: I'm using mysql for development and oracle for prod

Comment: I am not able to answer about jpql-specific issues, if that was part of the question