# How to use more than 1000 values in IN condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, in-clause

I am using java. I have 2000 key values in object level and have to fetch the corresponding records for that values from the DB.  I found temp table advice
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause), but won't it affect performance? How do I insert those values in a single shot, so that I can reduce the number of DB calls?

Comment: The temporary table is the accepted solution. Why do you think it affects performance?

Comment: Example code and values would be useful.

Comment: You could user JOINs instead of INs.

Comment: If you know that the number of values will always be 2000 (or around that), Evgeniy Dorofeev's solution will be the fastest and pretty easy to code. If the number of values can be higher, there will be a point where the temp table will be faster.

Comment: @Daniel How to insert 2000 rows in a single DB hit? Thats what my doubt is.. I can write some logic and split into 1000, 1000 records and do batch update.. It will take 2 DB hits only..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
col1 in (1,2...)  or col1 in (1001, 1002...)
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy.. I think I can write some code logic and populate it dynamically..

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the temp table is the way to go. Will it affect performance? Yes, it might be slightly slower than just hardcoding all of the values. But you can't have everything -- if you don't want to hardcode all of the values, you'll have to accept a small decrease in performance. I think the trade-off is satisfactory, particularly since the impact will probably be quite small.

Answer (score 1):

for a single in clause - you cant. see discussion [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=428758).