# how to extend the maximum number of expression in a list of oracle?

Tags: php, oracle

I am using an IN clause, whereby, it needs to search the id IN these set of IDs that are not in order, meaning, it came from a different criteria., how to solve this ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM "projeck"."mytable" "t" WHERE staffID IN (75953,196262,196387,133585,195639,196702,195790,195820,192903,145383,179603,175896,176554,43545,154843,183798,195767,195715,etc..etc.. etc..)
```

and i am getting this oracle error

```
General error: 1795 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause

Comment: the thing is, those set of digits are ought to change all the time, how am i gonna put that in a consecutive order?, it's each digit is random ...

Comment: where are they retrieved from? why do they need to be entered in order?

Comment: they are coming from a result of a different query from a function... and so, I have that set of random set..and i need to use IN clause in order to check if this staffID i have is among those search result..and that search result changes all the time...it is not always in order...

Comment: is the other query from the same db?

Comment: Just drop your function's query into the IN clause.  Don't worry about the order.

Comment: the query is not from another DB..it's the same db

Comment: Any chance you can put that query into the IN clause as a subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first choice would be to reference the function that generates these values directly.

If the values were being used for multiple queries and were expensive to calculate then I'd think about loading them into a global temporary table and joining to it.