# How to handle efficient database connection and performance in java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have 5000 records as search result and based on product number have to pull the related data associated with product number.that means seperate the 5000 product number and sending to database to pull the data.Creating one query and hiting the database for each product number is not efficient.

I'm looking for some idea to handle this situation. 
Note:using hibernate and oracle and java

Comment: You have an SQL query that returns 5000 rows? What's the problem?

Comment: I would suggest to join the two tables, if I understand your question correctly. please give some more specific information regarding the structure of your tables.

Comment: Your query should ideally return only **relevant** results, meaning that any filtering better be done by database and not the front end.  If you truly require 5,000 records for your client needs and you're not concerned with the absolute **freshness** of your data set, then grab it in one call and be done with it.

Comment: @JavaWorld It is highly unlikely that you will ever display 5000 search results, let alone retrieve detailed information for 5000 products. So your first query should only retrieve basic information to display as the search result, do it in a single query, and limit the output to some reasonable number, say 50 records, letting the user page further if they wish. Retrieve full details for each product when the user requests more details.

Comment: Your correct.Thats way currently working.but have download button to download as pdf file which all related information instead of going single product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 5000 queries to get the result, you may use the [IN clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).
You should probably split it in chunks, however, since such long SQL queries can throw errors, or use a temporary table and do a [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause).

Answer (score 1):

You got that search result with some query, it might be simpler to reuse that query with a join to retrieve the related data.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use a Materialized View and some basic paging? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm