# org.hibernate.criterion - I need to OR together an arbitrary number of criterion?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a java application using (quite old) hibernate mapping to an oracle 11 database. I'm using the org.hibernate.criterion class to generate my queries (at least for this piece).

I recently hit a bug where one of the queries I'm generating using org.hibernate.Criteria produces a very large 'in' clause. Here's how the Java console displays the generated query:

```
select this_.foo as foo_1_2_3, this_.bar as bar_2_3_4, this_.id as id_5_6_7
from some_table inner join some_other_table inner join
where blah=bloo and this_.id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ......................... ?, ?, ?, ?) order by this_.id asc
```

where the number of `?` elements is >1000.

This in clause is so large that it triggers `ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000` error in our database.

Here's the Java code that adds the 'in' clause:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", getMassiveListOfIDs() ) );
```

(where I'm adding the >1000 element in clause, in other words)

According to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842453/is-there-a-workaround-for-ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is) just using multiple smaller 'in' clauses is the solution. Makes sense.

I've modified this so that it splits the lists before adding the 'in' queries, like so:

```
    List<Long> listOfIds = getMassiveListOfIDs();

    if(listOfIds.size()>=1000){ 
        List<List<Long>> listOfSublists = this.splitIntoSubArrays(listOfIds); 
        for(List<Long> subArray : listOfSublists){
            criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", subArray)); 
        }
    }else{
        criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", listOfIds));
    }
```

So now the generated query look like this:

```
select this_.foo as foo_1_2_3, this_.bar as bar_2_3_4, this_.id as id_5_6_7
from some_table inner join some_other_table inner join
where blah=bloo and
this_.id in (?, ?, .... ?, ?) 
and this_.id in (?, ?, .... ?, ?) 
and this_.id in (?, ?, .... ?, ?) 
and this_.id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
order by this_.id asc
```

where each of the `(?, ?, .... ?, ?, ?)`  arrays actually contain 1000 elements, and the last is the remainder.

The problem is these are `AND` and not `OR` I want to OR all of the in clauses(in other words, I want to fetch any rows that have the id listed in ANY of these clauses), like:

```
select this_.foo as foo_1_2_3, this_.bar as bar_2_3_4, this_.id as id_5_6_7
from some_table inner join some_other_table inner join
where blah=bloo and (
this_.id in (?, ?, .... ?, ?) 
OR this_.id in (?, ?, .... ?, ?) 
OR this_.id in (?, ?, .... ?, ?) 
OR this_.id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
) 
order by this_.id asc
```

I know I could do something like this:

```
Criterion c1 = Restrictions.in("id", sublist1);
Criterion c2 = Restrictions.in("id", sublist2);
Criterion c3 = Restrictions.in("id", sublist3);
Criterion c4 = Restrictions.in("id", sublist4);

Criterion or1 = Restrictions.or(c1, c2);
Criterion or2 = Restrictions.or(c3, c4);

criteria.add(Restrictions.or(or1, or1) );
```

But I have no idea at compile time how big listOfIds will be. 500 or 10000.

is there a way to either

- Dynamically produce the ORing shown above
- OR an arbitrarily sized list of criterion together and add them to the query?

I realize this is a very niche question, so I would appreciate any help or advice. I've also massively simplified the examples for the sake of illustration.

Really, I'm looking for a Java Code solution, rather than a change to my database or hibernate mapping if at all possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out a very simple approach like:

```
Criterion restriction = Restrictions.in("id", listOfSublists.get(0));

for(int i=1; i<listOfSublists.size(); i++){
    restriction = Restrictions.or(restriction, Restrictions.in("id", listOfSublists.get(i)));
}
```

works just fine and produces the correct query.

I was getting strange queries being generated when I tried this the first time, and got caught up in how `.or` and `.and` methods were being strung together in examples, and how resulting queries would be parenthesized, but it turns out this works just fine, and those issues were unrelated to how I add the restriction in Java.

Next time I'll try a nap and a coffee before I put it to stack overflow...

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
if (arguments.size() > 1000) {
            Criterion criterionIn = Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1<>1");
            final List<Serializable> inList = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); i++) {
                inList.add(arguments.get(i));
                if (inList.size() == 1000) {
                    criterionIn = Restrictions.or(criterionIn, Restrictions.in(restriction.getField(), inList));
                    inList.clear();
                }
            }
            if (!inList.isEmpty()) {
                criterionIn = Restrictions.or(criterionIn, Restrictions.in(restriction.getField(), inList));
            }
            final Criterion criterionNotIn = Restrictions.not(criterionIn);
            return criterionNotIn;
        }
```

A complete example you can find on [github](https://github.com/danjee/generic-dao/blob/master/src/main/java/ro/fortsoft/generic/dao/HibernateGenericDao.java#l278)