# ORA-01795 maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the error

> ORA-01795 maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

for the below query

```
select emp_id, emp_name, emp_code
from emp e
where emp_id in (001,002,005,006....18000);
```

I need to put 18000 records in the `IN` clause. How can I achieve this? How can I modify my given query?

Comment: Put the 18000 records in a table and join with that.

Comment: You are completely abusing the `IN` clause.  And if you really only want to check all values between 1 and 18000, then you can express it with `where emp_id between 1 and 18000`. Isn't that good enough for you? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Have none of the answers from [all the previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=ora-01795) helped you? if not, why? Where are the values coming from, and where are you running the query from? (I'd probably use a table collection with member-of if you have an external list, e.g. in a Java array, but it depends..)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a workaround for ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842453/is-there-a-workaround-for-ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is)

Answer (score 0):

You can (and almost surely should) put the "records" (the values) in a table. Then you can do a join as @jpw suggested in a Comment; an IN condition is treated by the query engine as a join anyway.

Or, if you want to use the IN syntax, you still need the values in a table, and rewrite the condition as

```
... where emp_id in ( select id from this_table )
```

where "this_table" is the name of this new table, and "id" is the column name. The 1000 expression limit applies to expressions that you hard-code in the IN list, it does not apply to the number of results returned by a subquery.