# Does JdbcTemplate's queryForList has any limitation?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Recently, during a code review with a senior developer, he told me that there is a limitation with queryForList that it can only fetch 1000 records. But when I searched on the net I can't find any limitation. So is there any kind of limitation on JdbcTemplate's queryForList?

Comment: There's no limit. He may be confusing it with the fetch size, but that's a different thing, and even with that the default is unlimited (or rather "unspecified", so the driver default is used).

Answer (score 2):

Oracle database only allows for the maximum of 1000 records see the following error:

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000`

To resolve this, please see the following thread.
[Is there a workaround for ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842453/is-there-a-workaround-for-ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is)

Answer (score -1):

No, your developer is confusing it with `INSERT` statements, I presume you're using Oracle DBMS, where you can only insert upto 1000 records in a single statement.

Comment: That might be possible!