# ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 error in perl script

Tags: oracle, perl, oracle11g

I'm trying to run a query with NOT IN clause like:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE column NOT IN (?,?,...) (>1000 items)` and I'm getting ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 error.

In my script I'm doing something like:

```
my $lparam = join ', ' => ('?') x @ids; 
$lquery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column NOT IN ($lparam)";

$lcsr = $zdb->prepare($lquery);
$lcsr->execute( @ids );
```

I want to split the NOT IN clause to something like `where (A not in (a,b,c) AND A not in (d,e,f)) ...` How can we achieve this?

Comment: You might have to put your data in a temp table and check against that instead.

Comment: Temp table may cause a performance issue. Can we have any alternative in perl to split the array and use in multiple NOT IN clause?

Comment: Re "*Temp table may cause a performance issue*", One would be more inclined to believe that circumventing limits used to protect performance is more likely to do that. Anyway, it's bed time for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, adding triples and counting them.

```
my $count = 0;
$lquery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (A ";
while (@ids -$count > 3)  {
    $lquery .= "NOT in (?, ?, ?) AND A ";
    $count += 3;
}
my $lparam = join ', ' => ('?') x (@ids - $count); 

$lquery .= "NOT  IN ($lparam))";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the `IN` list using a combination of the column as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column,1) NOT IN ((?,1),(?,1),...) (>1000 items)
```

Here, 1 is used as the second column. And you can give more than 1000 values in the `IN` clause list. It is a workaround of skipping the limit.

Comment: So how can I modify my above perl code to create this NOT IN clause with the tuples?

Comment: Sorry but I am not an expert of the Perl.

Comment: you really should solve your problem by using a temporary table or refactoring the code... generating a massive list of NOT IN() values to check against is extremely poor form

Comment: @Tanami, It depends on the usage of the query, table structure, and indexes.

Comment: sure, in the same way that an expert knows when a goto is appropriate