# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis when create varray

Tags: oracle

In my program there are a lot of situation when i need to get additional information about knowing ids. So i have list of ids, which length may be very long (for example 100000 elements in it).

How i can use this list and transfer in oracle for getting sql without using temp tables?

No i try to use collection:

```
CREATE TYPE TEST_VARRAY IS VARRAY(5000) OF NUMBER(18);

SELECT G.ID, G.NAME FROM ANY_TABLE G
WHERE G.ID IN
(
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(
NEW TEST_VARRAY
(0,1,2,3... and so on ...,995,996,997,998,999)
)
);
```

there are 1000 numbers. And when I try execute this query the error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` tips is appeared! But if i delete first 0 (so we have 999 numbers) the sql is executed ok.

What is problem here?

Answer (score 5):

There is a limit in Oracle IN clause.

> A comma-delimited list of expressions can contain no more than 1000
>   expressions. A comma-delimited list of sets of expressions can contain
>   any number of sets, but each set can contain no more than 1000
>   expressions.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002792/why-oracle-in-clause-has-limit-of-1000-only-for-static-data)

Comment: Where are you see in this query "IN" clause?

Comment: SELECT G.ID, G.NAME FROM ANY_TABLE G
WHERE G.ID IN
(

Comment: You say about error "ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 tips". But in my case another error.

Comment: How can I to rewrite this query? The "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.." i put to query as parametr

Comment: @user1881712 The limit also applies for the number of parameters to an object constructor - in this case the VARRAY constructor. You can't create a varray with more than 1000 elements in the constructor.

Comment: Does exists way to create varray with more than 1000 elements?
I have list with more 1000 elements in C# program. How i can use this list in a query?

Comment: Read the links I have posted. They have answers for your question @user1881712

Comment: I saw them. The most popular answer is partitioned list into like
"IN (not more 1000 elements) OR IN (next not more 1000 elements) etc).
But this way also is not working. You can see the problem from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945895/ora-00913-error-when-use-a-lot-of-in-statement

Another solution - is using temp tables.
But I want to use collection

Comment: Any in statement like x in (1,2,3) can be rewritten as (1,x) in ((1,1), (1,2), (1,3)) and the 1000 element limit will no longer apply.

Comment: but what about collection?

Comment: I try this solution as (1,x) in ((1,1), (1,2), (1,3)) and the 1000 element limit. Yes it work on 10000 elements.
But when i use 100 000 elements it does't work (see my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945895/ora-00913-error-when-use-a-lot-of-in-statement)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you are misusing collections, at least I am not sure something like you did is good.

As far as I understand you generate this query before run, so what is the problem to do like that?

```
with ids as (select /*+ materialize */ 1 id from dual union all
             select 2 from dual union all
             select 3 from dual union all
             select 4 from dual union all
             /* repeat with the ids you need */
             select 9999 from dual)
select *
from yourTable, ids
where yourTable.id = ids.id;
```

And that's it! Without any limitations, with pure SQL only. I have added `materialize` hint to ensure it is not performance relevant, but I think it can be skipped.

No temporary tables, no collections, nothing to create and support. Just SQL.

If you will put ids out of `with` into `from` clause it will work in any RDBMS (I guess).