# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate doesn't work when IN clause more than 100 or 1000

Tags: java, spring

I am using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to run my query.  The query is like:

```
SELECT id, desc FROM tableA WHERE id IN (:custIds);
```

Now, I am calling a web service and it is returning a List of ids.  So I used NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to map the List of ids to "custIds".  However, I got an issue when the List of ids reaches more than 1000.  I've read that the DB will not be able to process a IN containing more than 100 or 1000.

As I am restricted to only receiving a List of ids, can you suggest what's best to use aside from NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Comment: How about creating a temporary table with the ids and using that in the query?

Comment: In my experience the limit on WHERE...IN comes from the database, not Spring JDBC.  See [How to put more than 1000 values into an Oracle IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause)   What database are you using?

Comment: Yes, I agree also that the limit in on database.  I'm using Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use more than 1000 entries in `IN` clause. There are few solutions as mentioned below:

- Use `inner query` to solve this issue. You can create a temporary table and use that in your `IN` clause.

sample query:

```
select id,desc from table_name where id in (select id from temp_table)
```

- Break it in the batch of 1000 entries using multiple `IN` clause separated by `OR` clause.

sample query:

```
select id,desc from table_name
  where
      id in (1,2,3,...1000)
  or
      id in (1001,1002,1003,...2000)
  or
      id in (2001,2002,...)
```

- Alternately use `union all` instead of `OR` clause as mentioned above with queries of 1000 entries in `IN` clause

sample query:

```
select id,desc from table_name where id in (1,2,3,4,...,1000)
union all
select id,desc from table_name where id in (1001,1002,...2000)
union all
select id,desc from table_name where id in (2001,2002,...)
```

[Read more..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause) and see [Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/64013/2/)