# ORA Exception with Hybris 5.6

Tags: oracle11g, sap-commerce-cloud

ORA-01795 maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 exception thrown when including B2B customer as a member of a B2B Unit.

Environment Hybris Commerce Suite 5.6.0 Oracle 11G

Reproducing the Issue

1. Create a B2B Unit in hMC / B2B Commerce / B2B Unit
2. Assign more than 1000 B2B Units as members (children) of the B2B Unit created on step 1
3. Include a B2B Customer as member (group) of the B2B Unit created on step 1
4. Log in store front with this B2B Customer.
5. As a result you are going to get Oracle exception ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned by VinayKumar](https://experts.hybris.com/questions/104125/ora-exception-with-hybris-56.html) on Hybris Experts, the cause is the 1,000 limit in Oracle, which is also discussed here: [How to put more than 1000 values into an Oracle IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause)

You need to split your queries by batches.