# CriteriaBuilder giving AND instead of OR in predicate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I want to update a date field in my table using `CriteriaUpdate` query.

I'm making this update based on the set of IDs filtered in `where in` clause.

This set of IDs can be greater than 1000, so in order to avoid [ORA-01795(1000 limit in in clause)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause), I'm partitioning the IDs list based into sub-lists of 999.

Here is my code:

```
@Modifying
public void updateDate(List<Long> ids, Date date) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaUpdate<MyTable> update = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(MyTable.class);
    Root root = update.from(MyTable.class);
    update.set("dateField", date);  // dateField present in MyTable entity.

    List<List<Long>> partitionedList = Lists.partition(ids, 999);
    List<Predicate> orPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
    partitionedList.forEach(partition -> {
        Predicate predicate = builder.or(root.get("id").in(partition));     // Id of MyTable entity
        orPredicates.add(predicate);
    });
    update.where(orPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
    entityManager.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
}
```

I was expecting generated query to be like:

```
update myTable set dateField=? where (id in (1, 2, 3.....9999)) OR ((id in (1000, 1001....))
```

But the generated query has AND instead of OR.

```
update myTable set dateField=? where (id in (1, 2, 3.....9999)) AND ((id in (1000, 1001....))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you believe that [`update.where(Predicate... restrictions)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaUpdate.html#where-javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...-) uses `OR` between the predicates? Javadoc says *"according to the **conjunction** of the specified restriction predicates"*, and "[conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)" means `AND`.

Comment: @Andreas, you're right. I missed this. Any suggestions on a suitable alternative?

Comment: What is the point of calling `builder.or()` with a single predicate? Telling the builder "here is a set of 1 predicate, please put `OR` between them (it) for me" seems rather ... meaningless. --- Seems you should remove `builder.or()` from inside the `forEach`, then apply it to the `orPredicates` array, and give that single predicate in the `where()` call.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Java 8 stream logic, do it this way:

```java
update.where(builder.or(
        Lists.partition(ids, 999).stream()
                .map(partition -> root.get("id").in(partition))
                .toArray()
        ));
```