# Making a SQL query that selects of list of values from more than one column

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a table which is something like this:

| AccountNum | Name | RoutingNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | name1 | r1 |
| a2 | name2 | r2 |
| a2 | name3 | r1 |

I want to select all rows with a specific pair account number and routing number, for example :

```
input
List<accountNum, routingNumber> pairList = {<a1, r1>, <a2, r2>}

sql returns:
| AccountNum | Name           | RoutingNum      |
| --------   | -------------- |--------------
| a1         | name1          | r1              |
| a2         | name2          | r2              |
```

For some context I just want to make a single call, that I would be making using jdbc, this is my java code which only selects for account number, which is not what I want as I want to select using routingNum too:

```
String inSql = String.join(",", Collections.nCopies(plainAccountNumberEntries.size(), "?"));
        List<String>accountNumberList = Arrays.asList("a1", "a2");

        return ddsJdbc.query(
                String.format("SELECT * from table where AccountNum in (%s)", inSql),
                accountNumberList.toArray(),
                new someMapper()
        );
```

I want to avoid making multiple calls to the database for every entry in the list.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is a bit unclear.  Are you asking to select rows with `((AccountNum="a1" and RoutingNum="r1") or (AccountNum="a2" and RoutingNum="r2"))`?  Or is it `AccountNum in ("a1","a2") and RoutingNum in ("r1","r2")`, which would also return `[a1,r2]` and `[a2,r1]` rows?

Comment: sorry if it is I am asking to return (AccountNum="a1" and RoutingNum="r1") or (AccountNum="a2" and RoutingNum="r2"))

Comment: Well, there's you `WHERE` clause.  If you have a variable number of conditions you'll have to build the statement dynamically each time. But please use placeholders (`?`) instead of building in the values, to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I am using placeholders ,ain't i? Also what do you mean by where clause , is it generating separate sql in a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IN` condition with multiple expressions in the list:

```sql
SELECT *
from   table_name
where  ( AccountNum, RoutingNum ) in ( ( 'A1', 'R1' ), ( 'A2', 'R2') )
```

Comment: Just a caveat for using 'IN' that I found , for oracle it has a hard limit of 1000 entries per call.

Comment: @Snedden27 Only for single value lists; lists with multiple values, like this one, can have up to 100,000 elements in the list. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17019130/1509264

Comment: well that's good, to know ,was thinking of batching the sqls but this helps , thanks